# WIFI Analysis tool

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I have setup an ad-hoc network between a Laptop and a MobileDevice.

I am using WifiManager Package from Android to get the RSSI value in the mobile device.

Can you please suggest some free tools or commands in Windows / Linux to obtain the Recived Signal Strength from the ad-hoc network tool.

I am currently using iwconfig/iw commands in Ubuntu. Would be glad if you have some other sugestions.

Thanks
Kiran

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried inSSIDer?

[inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider)

From that link:

> What's Unique about inSSIDer?
>   Compatible with Windows XP, Vista and 7 (32 and 64-bit) 
>   Uses the Native Wi-Fi API and your current Wireless network card 
>   Sort results by Mac Address, SSID, Channel, RSSI and "Time Last Seen" 
>   Compatible with most GPS devices (NMEA v2.3 and higher)
>
> How can inSSIDer help me?
>   Inspect your WLAN and surrounding networks to troubleshoot competing access points 
>   Track the strength of received signal in dBm over time 
>   Filter access points in an easy-to-use format 
>   Highlight access points for areas with high Wi-Fi concentration 
>   Export Wi-Fi and GPS data to a KML file to view in Google Earth. 
>   Filter through hundreds of scanned access points

Comment: Thank You Very much for your suggestion. This tool looks very promising for my investigation. I am just curious, if there are some tools available where, I could monitor the Terminals (Mobile Device in my case ) for RSSI through the Access Point ( Laptop ) ???